# How can I add href to image source in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I want to add hyperlink (a href tag ) to `img.src=image_url +Trending_movie.poster_path`

```js
function Trending_movies_section(trending_movies) {
  const section = document.createElement('section');
  section.classList = 'section';
  trending_movies.map((Tending_movie) => {
    if (Tending_movie.poster_path) {
      const img = document.createElement('img');
      img.setAttribute('class', 'trending_images');
      a.href = "https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_img_src2";
      img.src = image_url + Tending_movie.poster_path;
      section.appendChild(img);
    }
  })
  return section
}
```

Comment: I think you're supposed to show the HTML instead of Javascript? Or I really get it wrong.

Comment: You need to wrap your `img` tag with the `a` tag in `html` and where your `a` is declared?

Comment: Can you please describe the expected and actual behavior?

Answer (score 1):

Just wrap in an anchor

No need to use map when you do not need the resulting array

```js
function Trending_movies_section(trending_movies) {
  const section = document.createElement('section');
  section.classList = 'section';
  trending_movies.forEach(movie => {
    if (movie.poster_path) {
      const img = document.createElement('img');
      const a = document.createElement('a');
      img.setAttribute('class', 'trending_images');
      a.href = "...";
      img.src = image_url + movie.poster_path;
      a.append(img)
      section.appendChild(a);
    }
  })
  return section;
}
```